# Add Custom Data to Rest Api response

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I tried to add custom data to the endpoint V1/categories but ended up with getting error

My code is below

1. **etc/extension_attributes.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface">
        <attribute code="banner_slider" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

**2.di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="banner_image_data" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\Model\CategoryRepository"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**3.Plugin**

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository as Subject;

class CategoryRepository
{

    /**
     * @param Subject $subject
     * @param CategoryInterface $data
     * @return CategoryInterface
     */
    public function afterGet(
        Subject $subject,
        CategoryInterface $data
    )
    {
        $extensionAttributes = $data->getExtensionAttributes();
        $extensionAttributes->setBannerSlider('sandesh');
        $data->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
        return $data;
    }
}
```

**My error**

```
 Call to undefined method Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryExtension::setBannerSlider()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace your files with the following code:

**1.etc/extension_attributes.xml**

```
<extension_attributes for="Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryInterface">
        <attribute code="banner_slider" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
```

**2.di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="banner_image_data" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\Model\CategoryRepository"/>
    </type>
```

**3.Plugin**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\Model;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface as Subject;

class CategoryRepository
{

    /**
     * @param Subject $subject
     * @param CategoryInterface $data
     * @return CategoryInterface
     */
    public function afterGet(
        Subject $subject,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryInterface $data
    )
    {
        $extensionAttributes = $data->getExtensionAttributes();
        $extensionAttributes->setBannerSlider('sandesh');
        $data->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
        return $data;
    }
}
?>
```

let me know if you need any further assistanse. don't forget to upvote and mark as answer :)

Comment: Thank you @Joao71 answer worked